# How do I render a nested array in CakePHP's view?

Tags: php, cakephp, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array that is compiled via the model in a CakePHP request. The array can be nested at a variable depth, and the content is to be returned to the user.

Currently the looping and rendering process for this array is completed using a function in the View element of the request. This function is first called at the base array's depth, and repeated for any array element that has further array children. eg.

```
function print_depth($elements) {
  foreach($elements as $element) {
    echo $element['title'];

    if($element['children']) {
      print_depth($element['children']);
    }
  }
}

print_depth($elements);
```

With this process, I can print out all levels of the array, whilst still keeping the markup flexibility within the view (hence, it is skinnable), but I imagine this is the incorrect location for the function that handles this.

Is there a more MVC-valid process for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper instead of putting a single function in the view code.

What you do sounds like rendering a tree, there is already a tree helper out there.

https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/View/Helper/TreeHelper.php

Answer (score 2):

From an MVC point of view it's probably right where it belongs, since it's the views responsibility to prepare data for visual representation. However for a more DRY approach, you could implement this functionality in a helper.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this be invalid simply because the function would be existing within the function that calls the view file? I know PHP will allow this, but thought it was frowning upon.

Comment: Generally I wouldn't call it invalid, it's just a little "dirty" because it could easily violate the DRY principle when needed in multiple views, and because it will become a globally accessible function, which some people might consider a violation of the MVC principle since it makes "internal" view functionality available outside of the view, however a helper would be available outside of the view too, so I'd say that's kind of splitting hairs. Anyways, for a clean approach you should use a helper, that's the recommended way to go.